# Change notification for self in NSMutableDictionary subclass

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutabledictionary, key-value-observing

I've subclassed `NSMutableDictioary` following mainly [this great blog post](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html).

Now in that subclass the dictionary itself subscribes to all its **values** in order to detect any changes. This bit works just fine and value changes are observed internally in that subclass.

However value changes should then be propagated to observers of the *dictionary*, i.e. observers of the dictionary (subclass) are supposed to get notified that the dictionary has changed.

Except I cannot figure out how to trigger that KVO notification - using

```
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"self"];
```

doesn't seem to have any effect so I'm kinda stuck.

How can an instance of the `NSMutableDictionary` subclass initiate a change notification for itself?

Comment: What do you mean "observers of the dictionary"? A dictionary can't be observed directly. Key-Value Observing is about observing an object for changes in its properties. You can't observe an object itself, per se. If the dictionary is serving as the property of another object, then you have to observe that object for changes in that property, but that will only emit change notifications when the property changes *via some method of that object*.

Comment: To subclass a dictionary you have to add `addObject` & `removeObject` methods to your class.  You can notify observers there by launching a KVO notification, notifying a delegate, or sending an NSNotification.

Comment: Or you could KVO the backing dictionary property.

Comment: @Logan Did all that as already described in the question. That's not the problem. Sending KVO notification for the subclass instance itself is not working.

Comment: @KenThomases Hmm.. OK, I guess I get your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already hinted by Ken KVO allows you to **observe properties** - not an object per se!

The [**Key-Value Observing Programming Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177-BCICJDHA) states, that

> Key-value observing provides a mechanism that allows objects to be notified of changes to specific properties of other objects.

In other words: **self can never be observed**.